# MeteorJS - Error invoking Method 'updatePostData': Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi guys I am working on MeteorJS right now and I can not seem to update the collection. I got the error:

Error invoking Method 'updatePostData': Internal server error [500]

here is my client side code:

```
Template.my_posts.events({
'submit #pupdate': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
            var pauthor = event.target.updateauthor.value;
            var ptitle = event.target.updatetitle.value;
            var pcontent = event.target.updatecontent.value;
            var pdate_pub = new Date()

            console.log(pauthor);
            console.log(ptitle);
            console.log(pcontent);
            console.log(currentUserId);
            console.log(pdate_pub);
            Meteor.call('updatePostData',ptitle,pcontent,pdate_pub,currentUserId,pauthor);
        }
});
```

Here is my server side code:

```
Meteor.methods({
'updatePostData': function(ptitle,pcontent,pdate_pub,currentUserId,pauthor) {
            var selPostId = Session.get('selPostId');
            webPost.update(selPostId, {$set: {
                title: ptitle,
                content: pcontent,
                p_author: pauthor,
                date_pub: pdate_pub,
                author_id: currentUserId
            }});
        }
});
```

Please help, thank you

Comment: If you looked in your server logs you would probably find a message saying that `Session` object is not available server-side. You should instead pass your `selPostId` as an explicit argument to your method, or use some database related store to retrieve it on the fly.

Comment: @apendua - yes it is saying "session is not defined", let me try to use this._id in replacement of session.

Comment: still not working, I have tried re-declaring the session again in the server side but not working :(

Comment: I think I get it, session only works in the client side. . . hhhmmm i wonder how to pass it in the server side so I can use it . . .

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!! HAHAHA . . declared the session in the client side then pass it to the meteor.call and then call the variable in the server